# fread or read_csv by specific number of columns using r

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in r and working on my first project with r. 
- I have csv file about 4m records and 46 columns
- Out of 46 columns, last 2 columns are "Team-A COMMENTS" and "Team-B COMMENTS".
- Since these are comments, users have put double quotes and commas within comments because of which CSV treats them as another columns and shifts the data to more than 46 columns.

When trying to import this file using fread / read_csv it gives error as 
"Expecting 46 cols, but line 627872 contains text after processing all cols......."

Is there a way to import this data by ignoring the additional data after 46th column

Comment: Does adding `fill=TRUE` to `fread` help?

Comment: it din't unfortunately :(

Comment: You'll find an answer here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109

Comment: Gautam, I went through the link but honestly I couldn't get a clear answer.. or may be its going from top of my head since im a beginner. any alternatives please

Comment: If this is a one-time import, you can put a fake row at the top with only 46 columns.

Answer (score 0):

In `read_csv`,setting the `col_select` argument to `1:46` will fix the problem

```
read_csv(file.csv,col_select=c(1:46))
```

Comment: re-edited it to make it a statement not a question